# How to return a Dataframe in Azure ML from a python script

Tags: python, web-services, azure, dataframe, azure-machine-learning-service

I have the below Python script. And I'm trying to return the new Dataframe created. Unfortunately, I'm getting "NotImplementedError:"

Please let me know, how to return a Dataframe in Azure ML from a python script

Code:

```
def azureml_main(df) :

    therm_patterns,therm_missed_patterns = thermostat_phase(df)
    th_pat = json.loads(therm_patterns)
    missed_th_pat = json.loads(therm_missed_patterns)

    light_patterns, light_missed_patterns = light_phase(df)
    lt_pat = json.loads(light_patterns)
    missed_lt_pat = json.loads(light_missed_patterns)

    for j in range (0,len(lt_pat)):
        for i in range (0,len(lt_pat[0]['John'])):
            th_pat[0]['John'].append(lt_pat[0]['John'][i])
    for j in range (0,len(lt_pat)):
        for i in range (0,len(lt_pat[0]['Jane'])):
            th_pat[0]['Jane'].append(lt_pat[0]['Jane'][i])
    for j in range (0,len(lt_pat)):
        for i in range (0,len(lt_pat[0]['Jen'])):
            th_pat[0]['Jen'].append(lt_pat[0]['Jen'][i])

    for j in range (0,len(missed_lt_pat)):
        for i in range (0,len(missed_lt_pat[0]['John'])):
            missed_th_pat[0]['John'].append(missed_lt_pat[0]['John'][i])
    for j in range (0,len(missed_lt_pat)):
        for i in range (0,len(missed_lt_pat[0]['Jane'])):
            missed_th_pat[0]['Jane'].append(missed_lt_pat[0]['Jane'][i])
    for j in range (0,len(missed_lt_pat)):
        for i in range (0,len(missed_lt_pat[0]['Jen'])):
            missed_th_pat[0]['Jen'].append(missed_lt_pat[0]['Jen'][i])

    output = json.dumps(th_pat)

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: v[0] for k, v in json.loads(output) 
    [0].items()}, 'index' ).rename_axis('User').reset_index()


    return df
```

Error:

```
  Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please  
  view the output log for more information:

   ---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
   Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call  
   last):

       File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 211, in batch
       xdrutils.XDRUtils.DataFrameToRFile(outlist[i], outfiles[i], True)

       File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrutils.py", line 54, in DataFrameToRFile
       xdrwriter.write_attribute_list(attributes)

       File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrwriter2.py", line 155, in   
       write_attribute_list
       self.write_object(value)

       File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrwriter2.py", line 215, in write_object
       write_func(flags, converted, missingIndices)

       File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrwriter2.py", line 185, in write_objects
       self.write_object(value)

       File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrwriter2.py", line 200, in write_object
       raise NotImplementedError('Python Bridge conversion table not    
       implemented for type [{0}]'.format(value.getType()))

       NotImplementedError: Python Bridge conversion table not implemented  
       for type [<type 'list'>]

       Process returned with non-zero exit code 1
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble with using Pandas dataframes in azureml_main(). Microsoft tell me there's a fix coming out on 1/18/2017. Hopefully it will fix your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Look like your dataframe contains tuple as a value of a column. Azure machine learning workspace doesn't support tuples in dataframe as of now.

Answer (score -1):

The best Idea is to return it as a CSV file( geniune option in azure python Script) and later you can transform it back to df if you wish. But I do belive that csv file is the final product you need

Comment: how do you return a CSV file from Execute Python script module in ML studio?